# How to navigate to navigation screen one signal notification is received?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, onesignal

I want to navigate to notification screen on opened but the i do not receive any navigation props in App.js. How can i navigate to notification screen from app.js. ....................................................................................................................................................

App.js

````
import OneSignal from 'react-native-onesignal'; // Import package from node modules

export default class App extends Component {

constructor(properties) {
    super(properties);
    OneSignal.init("YOUR_ONESIGNAL_APPID");

    OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
    OneSignal.configure();  // triggers the ids event
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    OneSignal.removeEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
    OneSignal.removeEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
    OneSignal.removeEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
  }

  onReceived(notification) {
    console.log("Notification received: ", notification);
  }

  onOpened(openResult) {

    console.log('openResult: ', openResult);

    this.props.navigation.navigate("Notification");   /// there is no navigation props here in app.js
  }

  onIds(device) {
    console.log('Device info: ', device);
  }
}```

Navigate.js

```const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Settings: SettingsScreen,
    About: About,
    Notification: Notification
  },
);

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: DrawerNavigator,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
));
````

Answer (score 0):

Only screens are provided with the `navigation` props automatically. Your `<App />` component is not a navigation screen and thus `this.props.navigation` will always be undefined.

You should move the event listener to a screen. For instance it could be part of `AuthLoadingScreen` since it will always be loaded once.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to move your OpenSignal listeners where navigation is initialized then use navigation. Now you will definitely get `this.props.navigation undefined error`. In this case you can use these listeners in `AuthLoadingScreen`  .